# How to use js-flags in chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium, v8

I am using Chromedriver to automate tasks. However I want to use chrome flags. The problem is that it does not execute the --js-flags="--myflag". Currently I have:

```
opts = Options()
opts.binary_location = binary_location
opts.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
opts.add_argument("--start-maximized")
opts.add_argument(
    '--js-flags="--print-wasm-code"')
```

The --no-sandbox and --start-maximized work fine, however it does not use the --js-flags. I tried different js-flags but none are used.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the flags as mentioned below?

```
opts = Options()
opts.binary_location = binary_location
opts.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
opts.add_argument("--start-maximized")
opts.add_argument("--js-flags=print-wasm-code")
```

I have not used the '--js-flags' personally in my tests, however, I have used some other chrome flags where some value was passed to the flag. (e.g- [autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required](https://gist.github.com/ckzgraphics/6514a74fe5c83feb5c54982541ea67ff)).

Maybe you can look up some online resources and open source codes for your reference - https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions/addArguments

You can find the list of Chrome options here -

- http://www.assertselenium.com/java/list-of-chrome-driver-command-line-arguments/
- https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Hope this helps!

Comment: `"--js-flags=print-wasm-code"` is definitely incorrect; the `--` part of `--print` must be there. I don't know what the right answer is, but this is not it.